# Does create() method save model object to Django database?

Tags: django, django-models, class-method

I just came across using `create` methods in Djangos `models.Model` subclass. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/) has this example code:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        book = cls(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
```

Does this already save new `Book` object to database? My intuition suggests that `save()` method should be called on the line `# do something with the book` or else it should not work. However when I try testing it, it seems that addin `save()` to it does not affect anything what so ever. Why is that the case and how does it actually save object to database?

PS. I came across this while trying to learn testing with `TestCase`. If classmethod does not save anything to database problem is probably my testing code, but that would be whole another question.

Comment: No, you create an object, that is all.

Comment: So adding ``save()`` where I suggested should then actually save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this already save new `Book` object to database?

**No**, it just creates a `Book` object with the given title, but it is not saved to the database, you thus should save it:

```
book = Book.create('Pride and Prejudice')
book.save()
```

it might be better to work with [**`.objects.create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create), this will call save with `force_insert=True`, which will slightly optimize the insertion to the database:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        # will store this in the database
        book = cls.objects.create(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book
```

or with:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        book = cls(title=title)
        # will store this in the database
        book.save(force_insert=True)
        # do something with the book
        return book
```