# Why does my Django test pass when it should fail?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-models

I am new to testing of any sorts in coding. This is followup on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73175774/14694631) to my question. Answer establishes that this type of model method should not save object to database:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, user, name):
    list = cls(user=user, name=name) 
    return list
```

If this is the case I am curious why does this test pass and says everything is ok?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import List
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ListTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user_1 = User(username="test_user", password="abcd")
        user_1.save()
        List.objects.create(user=user_1, name="mylist")
        List.objects.create(user=user_1, name="anotherlist")
        
    def test_lists_is_created(self):
        user_1 = User.objects.get(username="test_user")
        list_1 = List.objects.get(user=user_1, name="mylist")
        self.assertEqual("mylist", list_1.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the test passes is that you call a different method from the one that you've implemented.

The line in `ListTestCase.setUp()`

```py
List.objects.create(user=user_1, name="mylist")
```

actually, call the Django's `QuerySet.create()` method. Notice that it's call via `List.objects.create()` not `List.create()`. Therefore, the object is saved in the database and the test passes.

In your case, you've implemented a method `create()` inside the `List` model, so you should call `List.create()`.